# Desktop system (Intel based) won't run with latest 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

My desktop system (with Intel motherboard) was working fine with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, but after the software update (approx 1 week ago) it only boots to a frozen log-in screen and was unusable.

I got the system running again with an early DVD for 17.10. The system has an ATI Radeon X1300 Pro GPU, and I can see in 17.10 `lspci` statements for:

```
kernel driver in use: radeon.
```

It is currently working with 17.10 on 4.13.0 32/35.

Can anyone explain why this system may have stopped working with 16.04.3, please?

Comment: This problem is still not fixed.  I have found that lshw -c video shows the display in 17.10

Comment: But not in 16.04.3 where it says unclaimed

Comment: Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: I can run this system in 16.04.3 recovery mode with 4.13.0 36/40 but the screen is not recognised.  With 17.10 it runs normally.

Comment: My system will still only run the latest 16.04.3 36/40 in recovery mode, producing on-screen text sizes that are far too large, and the command  lshw -c video saying *-display:0 unclaimed.  A normal boot with 36/40 does not complete.  The system runs correctly with 17.10. Can anyone help or suggest further diagnostics?

Comment: There is a clear difference between the correct screen handling on 17.10 compared to 16.04.3:

Comment: This is still not working, and there is a clear difference between correct screen handling on 17.10 compared to 16.04.3 where lshw -c video shows display:0 UNCLAIMED    Can anyone explain?

Comment: My 16.04 problem shows up in dmesg "VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting" and then "ERROR:  no UMS support in radeon module". It seems this is the same problem found by others - see bug 1568211.  I still haven't found any solution - can anyone help?

Comment: This fault is now raised as bug 1754571.